# Punctuation immediately after a question mark in a quote?

Tags: punctuation, commas, quotes, question-mark, quotation-marks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I punctuate around quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/how-should-i-punctuate-around-quotes)
>   [Comma placement when using quotes that end with a question mark](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46675/comma-placement-when-using-quotes-that-end-with-a-question-mark)

Say you're quoting someone with a requirement for a punctuation, how do you follow with your own punctuation?

e.g.,

```
"Are you crazy?," she asked incredulously.
"Wow!," said the cat.
```

Both of these example seem awkward. Do I just leave out the comma?

Answer (score 3):

Leave out the commas altogether. They add nothing. So, like this:

> "Are you crazy?" she asked incredulously.
>
> "Wow!" said the cat.