# "What happens to the comma after an inquiring/exclaiming quotation?", he wondered, as he posted to StackExchange

Tags: commas, quotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I punctuate around quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/how-should-i-punctuate-around-quotes)

Forgive me for the creative title, because I'm not sure how else to ask this.

If you have a sentence like this...

"What's wrong?", he asked sympathetically, hoping for an honest answer.

or like this...

"Hey! Give me my keys!", he shouted, as he shook his fist.

Is the comma to the right of the quotation mark correct? It seems odd to me, as the !/? already counts as 'punctuation'.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need the comma after the closing quotation mark in each example.

> "What's wrong?" he asked sympathetically, hoping for an honest answer.
>
> "Hey! Give me my keys!" he shouted, as he shook his fist.

Comment: Thank you! I shouldn't have second guessed my intuition!