# Should there be a question mark in a quoted question?

Tags: grammaticality, question-mark

This is the tweet I want to tweet:

> All people repeat after me - I pledge I will not ask every co-worker I
>   run into on Monday, 'how was your weekend'.

Should there be a question mark after "weekend"? Are there any other grammatical problems with this tweet?

Comment: ...........Why not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I punctuate around quotes?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/how-should-i-punctuate-around-quotes)—a question from 2010. The only reason I hesitate to recommend that Q&A wholeheartedly is that the question there seems to misrepresent "the American convention" regarding such punctuation. The answer by Old Pro there correctly describes the approach endorsed by _The Chicago Manual of Style_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you quote a question, you should put a question mark inside the quotation marks. Thus, there should be a question mark after *weekend*:

> I pledge I will not ask every co-worker I run into on Monday, 'How was
>   your weekend?'.

Comment: As Reg Dwight has said, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. [This] is not really a topic for a site for linguists and etymologists, and we don't want it to become a topic.'  (Though the question has probably been asked before in the early years of ELU.) It's also general reference.

Comment: +1 However, I would consider also capitalising the "H" in "how".

Comment: The advice given in this answer does not reflect the standard approach in U.S. publishing to punctuating a sentence that ends with a quotation containing embedded end punctuation. In the many U.S. publishing houses that I have copyedited for, the standard approach is to omit the final period (end point) so that the sentence would end with _weekend?'_ Normal U.S. punctuation style would also use double quotation marks instead of single ones for the quotation itself. See Old Pro's answer in the link contained in my comment beneath the OP's question.