# How would write this?

Tags: punctuation, commas

In a list, should it be 'A,' 'B,' 'C,', etc., or 'A', 'B', 'C'?  Should commas go inside or outside?

Comment: Presumably the commas are not parts of the literal strings being quoted, so they should be outside the quotes.  The exception to this is that *some* styles would have you place a comma at the end of a quoted complete sentence, when followed by `Peter said.` or something of that nature.

Comment: The finer points of punctuation are a matter of style. Adhere to the guidance of your editor, or of your favorite [style guide](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052).

Answer (score 2):

In general, BrEng prefers putting the comma outside of the quotation marks, while AmerEng puts them inside. Because of this, neither is universally accepted as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Often in technical publishing, *single* quotes are reserved for literal references.  Contextual punctuation in this usage is kept outside the single quotes.

> *‘A’,  ‘B’,  . . .*

means the following list:

> A 
>     B 
>     . . .

Whereas

> *‘A,?’,  ‘,,B,,’,  . . .*

means this bizarre list:

> A,? 
>     ,,B,, 
>      . . .

This allows linguists, grammarians, and computer scientists to unambiguously write about sentences, punctuation, and computer code.

**Except**: Even in technical writing, just as elsewhere, quotes within quotes alternate between single and double quotes:

> ‘Well, I'd hardly finished the first verse,’ said the Hatter, ‘when the
>   Queen jumped up and bawled out, “He's murdering the time! Off with his
>   head!” ’

That's how Lewis Carroll used double quotes within single quotes in *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*. The modern preference, however, is to have double quotes outermost:

> “Well, I'd hardly finished the first verse,” said the Hatter, “when the
>   Queen jumped up and bawled out, ‘He's murdering the time! Off with his
>   head!’ ”

This double-quotes-outermost preference is supported by The Chicago Manual of Style in an answer to [How should I punctuate around quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66964/154471).