# Do I need a comma after this question mark?

Tags: punctuation, commas, writing-style, question-mark

I want to write the folowing sentence in some work:

- *You went there on Thursday?* for instance, is not an interrogative clause but a declarative one, even if the utterance may be a question.

In the format that I am expected to use, sentences like this should appear without any quotation marks, but in Italics. The parenthetical *for instance* needs, in my opinion to be set off by commas. However, if I put a comma after the question mark, it looks very odd indeed:

- *You went there on Thursday?*, for instance, is not an interrogative clause but a declarative one, even if the utterance may be a question.

What should I do in this instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What does your style manual say? The *Chicago Manual of Style* makes this a typographical issue, noting that when two different marks appear at the same location, only the stronger is retained.  (Exceptions occur for certain instances involving quotation marks, parentheses, brackets, and dashes, but none of those is germane here.)  Another typographical consideration for *CMS* is that the type face of a mark is set in the face of the preceding word.  Although it's likely most readers wouldn't notice that the comma you're considering would be oddly italic.

Obviously, the typographical consideration is in conflict with the utilitarian  directive to set off asides with commas.  Although the following doesn't present a general solution, it's easy to avoid this particular conflict:

> For instance, *You went there on Thursday?* is not an interrogative clause but a declarative one, even if the utterance may be a question.

Comment: Style manual? That's a bit like a recipe I saw yesterday that had as one of the ingredients: leftover wine. Leftover wine?

Answer (score 15):

***Chicago's position***

*The Chicago Manual of Style*, 15th edition (2003) asserts this broad rule against combining question marks (or exclamation points) and commas (or periods):

> **6.123** *When to omit comma or period.* Neither a period (aside from an abbreviating period) nor a comma ever accompanies a question mark or an exclamation point. The latter two marks, being stronger, take precedence over the first two. ...

*Chicago* then offers two examples of this rule in action that are relevant to Araucaria's question:

> > "Have you read the platform?" asked Mark.
> >
> > Her favorite songs are "Hello Dolly!" "Chicago," and "Come with Me."

I must say that I find the "Hello, Dolly!" example somewhat problematic. In that case we're dealing with song titles, and elsewhere *Chicago* specifies that song titles should appear in quotation marks—which conveniently frames each title in the series given above. (Inadvertently or not, *Chicago* omits the comma that is supposed to appear after *Hello* in the song title "Hello, Dolly.") But what if we were dealing with movie titles (which *Chicago* says should appear in italics)? Would *Chicago* insist on the following punctuation of a series of four movies?

> Her favorite movies are *What Did You Do in the War, Daddy?* *Hello, Dolly!* *Chicago*, and *Harold & Kumar Go to White Castle*.

It seems to me that *Chicago*'s blanket rule banning the commas after "Daddy?" and "Dolly!" in that list doesn't do readers any favors in this case.

---

***Garner's position***

Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage*, second edition (2003) is less absolutist on this point than *Chicago* is:

> A question mark follows every question for which an answer is expected. Typically, the next word begins with a capital letter. "He asked me, 'Why are you here?' A foolish question." But it's also possible to have a midsentence question mark—e.g.,: "Why should what is supposed to be a sacrament be performed with everyone looking on?—with that most desolating of all assemblages, a family reunion." Edmund Wilson, "Things I Consider Overrated" (1920), in *From the Uncollected Edmund Wilson* 127 (1995). Most authorities recommend not placing a comma after the question mark in such a sentence,; yet, though it seems a little old-fashioned, Wilson's em-dash after the question mark is quite acceptable.

In other words, the punctuation "everyone looking on?—with that" is quite acceptable, but the punctuation "everyone looking on?, with that" is widely objected to.

---

***Oxford's position***

*The Oxford Guide to Style* (2002) doesn't directly address the question of adjacent question marks and commas, but it gives at least one example in which a comma is dropped from a sentence that might normally have had one if not for the presence of a question mark in the comma's expected place. The example occurs in a discussion of typical uses of question marks (section 5.8.1):

> > Where now? they wonder.

The focus of that example is the lowercase *they* (rather than uppercase *They*) following the question mark; but later in the same subsection, *Oxford* has this intriguing comment and example:

> When the question is a single word in a sentence, there is normally no introductory comma, there may be no question mark, and the word may be italicized:
>
> > He wondered why.
> >
> > The question is not whether but when.
> >
> > The questions 'who?', 'what?', and 'where?' remain to be answered.

Clearly, as far as *Oxford* is concerned, the presence of a quotation mark after a question mark makes adding a comma after the quotation mark A-okay. This situation wouldn't arise under *Chicago* rules because *Chicago* follows general U.S. style in placing commas inside quotation marks instead of outside them.

I don't know whether *Chicago* would have favored using quotation marks or italics here to identify the questions as questions, but neither approach is especially attractive in the absence of commas:

> > The questions "who?" "what?" and "where?" remain to be answered.
> >
> > The questions *who? what?* and *where?* remain to be answered.

If I were trying to punctuate the sentence while remaining obedient to the Chicaho guidelines, I would probably drop the quotation marks and the question marks and go with italics and commas:

> > The questions *who*, *what*, and *where* remain to be answered.

---

***Back to Araucaria's example***

Turning now to Araucaria's example—

> *You went there on Thursday?* for instance, is not an interrogative clause but a declarative one, even if the utterance may be a question.

—it seems to me that relying on an italicized question mark on one side of "for instance" and a comma on the other to set that phrase off from the rest of the sentence is distracting, inelegant, and awkward looking. The suggestion by deadrat that Araucaria transpose the order of the question and the "for instance" neatly evades the issue:

> For instance, *You went there on Thursday?* is not an interrogative clause but a declarative one, even if the utterance may be a question.

But what if Araucaria strongly prefers the original word order? In that case, it seems to me the only suitable evasion under *Chicago*'s rules is to set off "for instance" with something stronger than commas. The logical options are parentheses:

> *You went there on Thursday?* (for instance) is not an interrogative clause but a declarative one, even if the utterance may be a question.

or dashes:

> *You went there on Thursday?*—for instance—is not an interrogative clause but a declarative one, even if the utterance may be a question.

Or you could rebel against *Chicago* and argue that the question mark is an integral element of the question block at the beginning of the example sentence and that it doesn't provide meaningful independent punctuation assistance to the rest of the sentence, including the would-be parenthetical phrase "for instance." If we start from that position that adding a comma after the monolithic question block simply brings the structure of the rest of the sentence more quickly into balance and coherence:

> *You went there on Thursday?*, for instance, is not an interrogative clause but a declarative one, even if the utterance may be a question.

*Chicago* devotees (and others) may find the juxtaposition of question mark and comma unacceptably startling, but that punctuation has the great virtue of making clear immediately how the author is parsing his sentence—and the main purpose of punctuation, ultimately, is to promote clarity with regard to an author's intentions.

Comment: To add to your concerns about the "Hello, Dolly!" example, _Chicago_ also places the a comma inside the quotes when citing the name of the song, "Chicago", which I'm pretty certain runs counter to most style guides.  Quoting dialogue or prose and inserting a comma to suit the enclosing sentence's structure is one thing, but adding new punctuation to a title in quotes is quite another.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a comma is needed.

An easy way to understand this would be to remove the question mark and replace the sentence with a non-question, which then a comma would *still* be accepted. Therefore, it is perfectly fine to place a comma there.