# How do I use a question as an embedded quotation when it also deserves a comma?

Tags: commas, quotations, question-mark, comma-splices

- So I asked "Shall I do the thing?" and he responded with "Yes."

In that sentence, should the `?` exist? It kind of feels like it should be a comma, given its place in the sentence. Thing is, if I take away the comma, it loses its identity as a question.

What is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Question marks trump commas — leave the comma out.

Comment: That's interesting @PeterShor. Are you able to provide some more details about this rule and other uses in a full answer? I'd be happy to rename the question to make it more relevant for search.

Comment: It is a mix of direct speech and indirect speech. It should be either [So, I asked, "Shall I do the thing?" He replied, "Yes"] or, [So I asked if I should do the thing and he consented.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I punctuate around quotes where the punctuation required by the quote interferes with the punctuation of the sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/how-should-i-punctuate-around-quotes-where-the-punctuation-of-the-quote-interfer)

Answer (score 1):

In general, question marks and exclamation points trump commas. When a question mark (or exclamation point) and a comma should naturally both appear, the comma is left out.

According to [this blog](https://www.lawprose.org/lawprose-lesson-161-multiple-punctuation-marks/), the *Chicago Manual of Style* says

> When a question mark or exclamation point appears at the end of a quotation where a comma would normally appear, the comma is omitted.

The blog points out that there is an exception when the question mark or exclamation is part of a title. In this case, style guides offer differing advice on what to do.

Comment: A very obvious duplicate (multi- in fact), but I can't see the CMoS rule spelled out verbatim elsewhere.